# Add a new column in SQL Server with random numbers between 1 and 5

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an already filled database table in SQL Server; now I need to add a new column with random numbers from 1 to 5 (they can repeat).

There's just too many rows to fill that's not going to work for me to do it manually.

I searched on the internet but haven't found anything useful, does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm using Microsoft Sql 2018.

Comment: 1.Add a new column to the table. 2.Update the table, set values of the column. 3. Alter the table to set up new constraints. Which step is your problem?

Comment: Do you mean a column that has a `DEFAULT` value between 1-5, or a new column that will have a random number between 1-5 each time you reference it (and can be different each time)?

Comment: @Serg I need a Sql query that will fill the table for me, I added the column, just need the query to do my job basically since its a big database.

Comment: @Larnu Need to add the number as a new column, it's something like a review, it need to be random between 1 and 5 and it can repeat, since its a big database and there isn't enough combination to cover it all with numbers from 1 to 5 (they should be decimal)

Comment: That doesn't actually answer my question, @RadonjicLazar .

Comment: @Larnu It's a column with default value between 1-5, it shouldn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column using `ALTER TABLE` and give it a `DEFAULT` value at the same time. If you want to populate those values as well, use `WITH VALUES`:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID)
VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10);
GO
--Add new column with DEFAULT value (1-5)
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable ADD NewColumn int DEFAULT ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID()))%5+1 WITH VALUES;
GO
--Check values
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable;
--Add a new row
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (ID)
VALUES(11);
--Check value
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE ID = 11;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is:

```
select t.*,
       1 + floor( rand(newid()) * 5 )
from t;
```

You can incorporate this into an `update`:

```
update t
    set col = 1 + floor( rand(newid()) * 5 );
```

Comment: This is not working in `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   May 22 2023 22:22:02   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation ` because `Operand type clash: uniqueidentifier is incompatible with int`

Comment: * which, by the way, can be solved like embedding `rand(newid())` inside a `CHECKSUM()`